# Express select value from database directly to an array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, express

**Hi, I am creating rest api in express and mysql. I need to serve values from database to an endpoint and array should look like this:**

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 22, etc..]
```

**When i am selecting rows from table and adding it to an endpoint using: `res.json({rows})`, i have array like this:**

```
["number": 1, "number": 4, "number": 5, etc..]
```

**Is it possible to select "direct" values from table using MySQL, and serve them using `res.json({rows})`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, mysql always return the values in json formate. like

```
[{"number": 1}, {"number": 4}, {"number": 5}, etc..]
```

and if you want the result in an array of values then you simply use the map function of javascript.
e.g.

```
let rows = [{"number": 1}, {"number": 4}, {"number": 5}, etc..] // result from mysql
rows = rows.map(row => row.number);
console.log(rows) // [1,4,5, etc...]
```